Setting up an api for receiving Twilio messages, I can hit it with Postman but Twilio does not hit it
I have a server side Blazor website with an API set up for Twilio. I have Twilio pointing to the correct endpoint, and when I call it in Postman it works. However when I send an SMS in the API is never hit, why is that?
using Twilio.AspNet.Common;

namespace Webapp.Services.Controllers.API
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TwilioAPIController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public void ReceiveSms(SmsRequest message)
        {
            Logger.Log("Received SMS message: " + Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));
        }
    }
}

For reference, here is the Postman body that is working:
{
    "MessageSid": "",
    "SmsSid": "",
    "Body": "Hello",
    "MessageStatus": "",
    "OptOutType": "",
    "MessagingServiceSid": "",
    "NumMedia": 0,
    "ReferralNumMedia": 0,
    "accountSid": "removed",
    "From": "+11234567890"
}


Do you see any error?

No. The API is just never hit.

Can you check your error logs in the console and check if you see the attempted call of the endpoint there?
